# Mark and remove rows that differ only by values swapped between two columns as duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to remove rows from my database if the only difference between them is that `Sortname` and `Spouse_Sortname` are swapped.  The way I want to do this is to mark those for deletion by inserting a value of 1 in column `keep` otherwise place a 0 in column `keep`

```
recordID Sortname                 Spouse_Sortname        Keep    
3        SMITH Anne-Marie         ACTONTON John Michael  0    
683      BARON Peter Jack         BARON Jan Shirlely     0    
22       BARON Jan Shirlely       BARON Peter Jack       1    
28       QUINN Robert             QUINN Margaret Joy     0    
29       QUINN Margaret Joy       QUINN Robert           1
552      JOHNSTONE Brendan James  BROWN Julie            0
```

For example - see Record ID 683 and 22

`Sortname` in record ID 683 is the same as `Spouse_Sortname` in record ID 22 and vice-versa, so I only want to keep one of those records. Same applies to record ID 28 and 29.

I would like to find the records which are the same except that `Sortname` and `Spouse_Sortname` are swapped and mark the `Keep` column to look like my example.

It does not matter which one of the records it keeps as long as there is only one record left.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I've no idea what you're asking for help with.

Comment: sorry new to Stackoverflow having difficulty placing the image so I have updated my post above

Comment: Your sample data doesn't match your explanation. (683) `BARON Peter Jack` should be kept according to your description, as should (28) `QUINN Robert`. Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: @HABO - it's tagged with tsql, so its either sybase or sql server.

Comment: Why are both `BARON Peter Jack` and `QUINN Robert` not tagged with `1`?

Comment: Ok, so what I am trying to achieve is Record ID 683 and 22 both have each other in either the Sortname and the Spouse_Sortname but I only want to keep one of those records.  Same applies to record ID 28 and 29.  the only one that works perfectly is recordid 3 and 552.  So I would like the Keep column to look like my example.  Sorry thats the best explanation I can give.

Comment: how do you decide which one from 683 and 22 to keep

Comment: It does not matter which one of the records it keeps as long as there is only one record left.

Comment: Hi - this came to me in review for re-opening.  I've edited it to say what I think you want given the comments and your own edit.  Can you check the wording and verify that that is what you mean?  The edit history is [available here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29986938/revisions).

Comment: @J Richard Snape - that is correct

Answer (score 1):

these are the duplicates

```
select t2.*  
  from table t1 
  join table t2 
    on t1.name = t2.spouseName 
   and t1.spouseName = t2.name 
   and t2.recordID > t1.recordID -- this is how you keep one
```

Comment: If you use `recordID` (rather than the names) as a tie breaker then you don't need to worry about people with the same name being married to each other, e.g. Terry could be male or female.

Comment: @HABO - looks like the way to go

Answer (score 0):

This flags the rows with a higher recordID:

```
SELECT t1.*,
   CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tab AS t2
                    WHERE t1.Spouse_Sortname = t2.Sortname
                    AND t1.recordID > t2.recordID)
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
   END
FROM tab AS t1;
```

Comment: - I will try the above and advised tonight